# My web page sometimes ignores my css file

Tags: php, html, css, debugging, xampp

So I'm building a web application using HTMl CSS and PHP, and sometimes when I make changes to the css file, the web doesn't react to it and I can even delete the whole file and still doesn't change a thing in the browser and I have to copy everything from the css file into a different css file and use that one and after that it works but it often takes only a few minutes and i have to change it back so currently i have style.css and styles.css and depending on the situation i use either the first one or the other one but its annoying, I think it could be something with the server I'm running it on localhost using XAMPP. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You should read about files versioning. You can also open browser console (F12 or ctrl+shift+c) and in `network tab` check `disable cache`. Then, with opened console, you will have always fresh css. There is also shortcut to hard refresh: ctrl + F5.

Comment: Thanks @Robert that solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem come from browser cache.

- It's not only happened to CSS file, but to script as well.

There are many solutions for this:

If it's occur to production environment:

- You can versioning your script and stylesheet file

If it's just about developing in local environment:

- You can empty cache and hard reload the webpage (by opening devtool, right click in reload icon, select empty cache and hard reload or just simply use ctrl + f5). This will need to be done every time you have a change in script or stylesheet file

[image: Empty cache and hard reload]

- Or you can disable browser cache (open devtool by pressing f12, switch to `network tab` in browser devtool, and check `Disable cache`.
- I'm not recommend `Disable cache`. You should stick with `empty cache and hard reload`

[image: Disable cache]

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the browser's cache.

If you are using Windows or Linux, just go on the browser and hit `ctrl+f5` to clear the cache.
You can also click on google chrome's settings, then search for `Cookies and site data` and tap `Clear data`.

Or open Chrome's developer tools by pressing `F12` then open the Settings (`F1`). Find the checkbox labeled `Disable cache (while DevTools is open)` under the Network heading and turn it on so Chrome will no longer cache your CSS files and always load the latest version when the dev tools window is opened.